# PHP Regex on measures

Tags: php, regex

I have some strings and i would like to get the amount and the unit. Here is an example of the string and the like wanted array :

- 10 bags -> ["10","bags"]
- 10 lbs -> ["10","lbs"]
- 10 lbs of oak wood ["10", "lbs"] (i don't need the last part)
- 10 g ["10", "g"]
- 10 lbs of wood + 8 planks + 1 screw ["10", "lbs", "8", "1"]

Have you any idea ? I have a very large amount of "last part that i don't need" so i wouldn't use the str_replace function. Currently i try to find something to use with preg_match. I found something like this but i'm not good with regex to understand how to add the "+" handle and to avoid it match "10 g" on string like "10 grapes".

```
'/(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(lbs?|g|kgs?|pounds?|oz|ounces?|g|mg|ml)\b/'
```

Comment: Your regex does not match `10 b` in `10 bags`. It is good, just add `|bags?` alternative, see `(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(lbs?|g|kgs?|pounds?|oz|ounces?|m[gl]|bags?)\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmygbJ/1))

Comment: Regular Expressions are great at extracting text from strings that are **regular** ... I've a feeling that your input strings are going to be too irregular to be able to reliably parse with RegEx - I've a feeling that whatever we come up with, you'll have an input string that borks it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this pattern: `\d+(\s(bags|lbs?|g|kgs?|pounds?|oz|ounces?|mg|ml))?`

> Starting with a number, maybe follow by a space and some words, such
>   as: `bags`, `lbs`, `g`, `kgs`, `pounds`, `oz`, `ounces`, `mg`, `ml`

```js
var pattern = /\d+(\s(bags|lbs?|g|kgs?|pounds?|oz|ounces?|g|mg|ml))?/g;

console.log("10 bags".match(pattern));
console.log("10 lbs".match(pattern));
console.log("10 lbs of oak wood".match(pattern));
console.log("10 g".match(pattern));
console.log("10 lbs of wood + 8 planks + 1 screw".match(pattern));
```

p/s: I'm not making a copied version from @Wiktor comment, I haven't read comments before.

Comment: The question is taged PHP, not Javascript.

Comment: @Toto I'm not saying *You can do that in javascript*, I'm saying *I think you're looking for this pattern*

Comment: @Toto Regex pattern is an exception.

Comment: I disagree. Nevertheless, your output is not what is wanted. For example, the first result should be: `["10","bags"]`

Comment: @Toto Well, I'm just guessing the pattern based on the line `I found something like this but i'm not good with regex` which is posted by OP.

Comment: I have a list like about hum... 150-200 differents elements. If i add everything on the regex, it may be complicated to handle. Maybe i could generate the regex patern but what about the performances...